# Firestore - Deleting lot of documents without concurrency issues

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, concurrency

I have developed a game using Firestore, but I have noticed some problems in my scheduled cloud function which deletes rooms that were **created 5 minutes ago and are not full** OR **are finished**.

So for that, I am running the following code.

```
async function deleteExpiredRooms() {
  // Delete all rooms that are expired and not full
  deleteExpiredSingleRooms();

  // Also, delete all rooms that are finished
  deleteFinishedRooms();
}
```

Deleting finished rooms seems to work correctly with this:

```
async function deleteFinishedRooms() {
  const query = firestore
    .collection("gameRooms")
    .where("finished", "==", true);

  const querySnapshot = await query.get();

  console.log(`Deleting ${querySnapshot.size} expired rooms`);

  // Delete the matched documents
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    doc.ref.delete();
  });
}
```

But I am experiencing concurrency problems when deleting rooms created 5 minutes ago that are not full (one room is full when 2 users are in the room, so that the game can start).

```
async function deleteExpiredSingleRooms() {
  const currentDate = new Date();

  // Calculate the target date
  const targetDate = // ... 5 minutes ago

  const query = firestore
    .collection("gameRooms")
    .where("full", "==", false)
    .where("createdAt", "<=", targetDate);

  const querySnapshot = await query.get();

  console.log(`Deleting ${querySnapshot.size} expired rooms`);

  // Delete the matched documents
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    doc.ref.delete();
  });
}
```

Because during the deletion of a room, a user can enter it before it is completely deleted.

Any ideas?

Note: For searching rooms I am using a transaction

```
firestore.runTransaction(async (transaction) => {
  ...

  const query = firestore
    .collection("gameRooms")
    .where("full", "==", false);

  return transaction.get(query.limit(1));
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [BatchWrites](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes):

```
const query = firestore
    .collection("gameRooms")
    .where("full", "==", false)
    .where("createdAt", "<=", targetDate);

const querySnapshot = await query.get();

console.log(`Deleting ${querySnapshot.size} expired rooms`);

const batch = db.batch();

querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  batch.delete(doc.ref);
});

// Commit the batch
batch.commit().then(() => {
    // ...
});
```

> A batched write can contain up to 500 operations. Each operation in
> the batch counts separately towards your Cloud Firestore usage.

This should delete all the rooms matching that criteria at once. Using a loop to delete them might take a while as it'll happen one by one.

If you are concerned about the 500 docs limit in a batch write, consider using Promise.all as shown:

```
const deleteOps = []
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  deleteOps.push(doc.ref.delete());
});

await Promise.all(deleteOps)
```

Now to prevent users from joining the rooms that are being delete, it's kind of harder in a Cloud Function to do so as all the instances run independently and there may be a race condition.

To avoid that, you many have to manually check if the room that user is trying to join is older than 5 minutes and has less number of players. This is just a check to make sure the room is being deleted or will be deleted in no time.

```
function joinRoom() {
 // isOlderThanMin()
 // hasLessNumOfPlayers()
 // return 'Room suspended'
}
```

Because the logic to filter which rooms should be deleted is same, this should not be an issue.

Comment: how does this solve the concurrency problem? I mean, I thought that batched writes were useful for making sure that N documents are deleted at once, reverting if one of them fails.

Comment: @Raul did you mean preventing users from joining those rooms while they are being deleted?

Comment: yeah, that is what I mean

Comment: also not using batches for deletions because of the 500 limitation

Comment: @Raul please check the updated answer, also I'd prefer batched writes/Promise all over deleting documents using a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for **transactions** check out the documentation out here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions

Or watch the YouTube video that explains the concurrency problem and the differences between **batched writes** and **transactions**: https://youtu.be/dOVSr0OsAoU